# How to send request headers in "iron-form"?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.7.0. How do I send request headers in `<iron-form>`?

I tried this:

```
form.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function(event) {
    var headers = {'akash':'akash'};
    event.target.request.requestHeaders = headers;
    console.log(event.target.request.requestHeaders);
});
```

which logged the following text, but my headers were not present in the request.

`console.log(event.target.request.requestHeaders);` ==> `"Object {content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}"`

Answer (score 0):

The `<iron-form>.request` property is an `<iron-ajax>`, and `<iron-ajax>.requestHeaders` is actually *not* a settable property. Use the [`<iron-ajax>.headers`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#property-headers) property instead

```
form.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function(event) {
  var headers = {'akash':'akash'};
  event.target.request.headers = headers;
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ObdmmV?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

We can add Headers using this two ways :

1. `<form is="iron-form" id="form" 
               method="POST" action="/" 
               on-iron-form-response="responseHandler"
               on-iron-form-error="errorHandler"
                headers = '{"akash":"akash"}'>`
2. `<template>
    <content></content>
      <div class="layout vertical parent-style">
        <form is="iron-form" id="form" 
              method="POST" action="/" 
              on-iron-form-response="responseHandler"
              on-iron-form-error="errorHandler">
        </form>
       </div>`

   `

   ```
   function handleLoginAction(event)
    {
       var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.parentElement;  // Get Form ref from DOM.

       form.headers = "{'akash':'akash'}";

       form.submit();
    }

   form.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function(event) {
   console.log("Headers--------------");
   console.log(event.target.request.requestHeaders);   // {'akash':'akash'}
   });


    </script>
   </template>`
   ```